# Finding the region of analyticity of a function involving integration

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

I need to find, in fact, need to show that
$I(s)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{S(x)-x+½}{x^{s+1}}dx$

where
$S(x)=\sum_{n\leq x} \chi (n)$

is analytic in the region Re($s$)>-q and $\chi(n)$ is non principal character mod q

There could be error in the question as well. Please notify the same with solution. Thank you

Comment: How about using this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348115/ (there might be some issues with the $\infty$ bound)

Comment: I don't think it's that easy.. infinity bound part is correct

Comment: Can you not just do a substitution that transforms $[1,\infty[$ to some bounded interval (like $y=\frac1x$ or $y=\frac{x-1}x$) and then use the Theorem in the linked question?

Comment: If you can possibly write it down and post a picture, it'd be great. Coz I'm not able to do..

Comment: Set $y=\frac{1-x}x$. Then $$I(s)=\int_0^1 \frac{S\left(\frac1{1-y}\right)-\frac1{1-y}+\frac12}{\frac1{(1-y)^s}} \frac{1}{(1-y)^2}\,\mathrm dy. $$ Now the integrand seems analytical for fixed $y$ (check that).

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: I think this is a distracting idea.

Comment: If $\chi$ is non-principal, then $S(x)$ is bounded (w.r.t. $x$, i.e. for fixed $q$), and "$−x$" in the integrand becomes dominating. So you can only claim the analyticity in $\Re s>1$.

Comment: @metamorphy Does my idea not work ? It seems for fixed $y$ the Integrand is of the type $s\mapsto\frac{C}{c^s}$ for some constants $C,c$ so it doesn't look too bad... ?

Comment: fix $q$ and by Polya Vinogradov $|S(x)| \le 6\sqrt q \log q$; then let $s=0$ and notice that the integral is $\int_1^{\infty}(-1+c(x))dx, c(x)=O(1/x)$ and that is highly divergent